# Why are console.log calls showing up in a different order than they are written?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node.js and I think I don't understand how it's supposed to work. I'm using steam-tradeoffers, and in my mind, this should first go through one trade offer, then for each item I am going to receive, it loads their inventory and compares it to their inventory until it finds the matching item and prints it. However, it loads all the offers first, then loads all their inventories.

```
steam.on('webSessionID', function (sessionID) {
    steam.webLogOn(function (newCookie) {
        offers.setup({
            sessionID: sessionID,
            webCookie: newCookie
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            offers.getOffers({
                get_received_offers: 1,
                active_only: 1,
            }, function (error, body) {
                if (body.response.trade_offers_received) {
                    body.response.trade_offers_received.forEach(function (offer) {
                        console.log('TRADE OFFER')
                        offer.items_to_receive.forEach(function (offerItem) {
                            offers.loadPartnerInventory({
                                contextId: 2,
                                partnerSteamId: offer.steamid_other,
                                tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid,
                                appId: 730
                            }, function (err, items) {
                                var item;
                                // Load tradable items in inventory
                                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                                    if (items[i].tradable) {
                                        item = items[i];
                                        //if item matches item from their inventory we can get the market name
                                        if (item.id == offerItem.assetid){
                                            console.log(item.market_name)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });


    });
});
```

Output:

```
TRADE OFFER
TRADE OFFER
TRADE OFFER
Sticker Capsule 2
Sticker Capsule 2
Sticker Capsule 2
```

What I expect:

```
TRADE OFFER
Sticker Capsule 2
TRADE OFFER
Sticker Capsule 2
TRADE OFFER
Sticker Capsule 2
```

Could someone explain to me what is happening?

e: Example of this being annoying

```
                        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                            if (items[i].tradable) {
                                item = items[i];
                                //if item matches item from their inventory we can get the market name
                                if (item.id == offerItem.assetid){
                                    // Configure the request
                                    console.log(item.market_name)
                                    var options = {
                                        url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=' + item.market_name,
                                        method: 'GET',
                                        headers: headers
                                    }
                                    // Start the request
                                    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                                        result = JSON.parse(body)
                                        if (result['success'] == true) {
                                            console.log(item.market_name + " valued at " + result['median_price'])
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

output:

```
429313829
Sticker Capsule 2
429316197
Sticker Capsule 2
429315519
Sticker Capsule 2
Nova | Predator (Field-Tested) valued at &#36;0.09
Nova | Predator (Field-Tested) valued at &#36;0.09
Nova | Predator (Field-Tested) valued at &#36;0.09
```

As you see, the item should be Sticker Capsule 2, not the nova predator

Comment: This method `offers.loadPartnerInventory` is asynchronous. So the console.log are running before the callback from this method is called.

Comment: Thanks - how would I get this to run the way I want it to run? or is it working like I think it is minus the console.log?

Comment: Why do you care what order things get run in?

Comment: checkout Q promises as well ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get them to run in series like you expect, you need to account for the asynchronous nature of node's callbacks.

`body.response.trade_offers_received.forEach(function (offer) {`

could be replaced with something like this using the [fantastic async library](https://github.com/caolan/async).

```
require('async').series(body.response.trade_offers_received, function(offer, callback){
  //process the offer variable
  callback(); // <- call this to tell async that this item is done being processed.
});
```

Also though, you will definitely need/want error handling at some point, and maybe want to collect the results of all your actions in the final callback.

```
require('async').series(body.response.trade_offers_received, function(offer, callback){
  loadPartnerInventoryAsyncCall({offer: offer}, function(err, someOtherResult){
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }

    //process the offer variable
    callback(null, someOtherResults); // <- call this to tell async that this item is done being processed.
  });
}, function(err, allResults){
  if (err){
    console.log('one of my series functions had an error', err);
  }

  //do something with allResults, if you want
});
```

---

To try to clarify asynchronous requests with a simple example:

```
['google.com','yahoo.com','bing.com'].forEach(function(url){
  require('request').get(url, function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

because of network delays, I don't know which page result is going to get logged first! They could come out in any order!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated my main question with a problem I seem to be having doing this. Am I approaching this wrong? Do I need to use the async library?

Comment: Most times that you see a function as an argument that will be an async function (not all the time, but basically). If you see this, then you should not expect the code to run in the order that you see it written. Node will run the callbacks whenever it has the data, and run the console.log that exist inside in whatever order they happen to be run in. You don't have to use async, but you would need something like it by using promises (via bluebird, or Q, or something). If you don't use the library and want control of the order, then every 'step' in your code will need to be nested in the last.

Comment: I'm editing my answer with a simple example of why async messes up the order.

Comment: Thanks! In regards to your 'Nesting' in the last, in my example code, I feel like since I put the pricing check under an item match it should check for that item before going to the next item in the list, however it seems to not? Could you maybe give me an example of the nesting?

Comment: The forEach doesn't wait for the request to finish, it just flies through the loop and starts running them all in parallel

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now. What is the appropriate way to fix this? Should I use the async, or 'nest' it?

Comment: Nesting it gets RIDICULOUS fast.

You should read this article for a better understanding: http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html

And then use something like async module.

Comment: Also take a look at http://pouchdb.com/2015/03/05/taming-the-async-beast-with-es7.html if you want to avoid having to use callbacks at all.